# Overlapping/conflicting review bar bug

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits

While going through the Suggested Edits review queue, I was lucky enough to have a review audit as my last review of the day. After (correctly) reviewing it, I saw what I assume was S.O. trying to display both the "congratulatons" message and the "thank you for reviewing 20 suggested edits" message at once:

[image]

I arrived at the conclusion that it was both, and not just the one, because the question body is visible, which is something exclusive to audits. Normally when I reach 20 reviews, the body of the last reviewed question is not visible.

Comment: ... what double review bar? I only see the one...

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas That is the problem. One message is hidden. Perhaps the title is a bit misleading.

Comment: There's only so much acclaim that the devs can squeeze into SO

Comment: E_TOO_MUCH_POSITIVISM

Comment: It looks like the error is correct but you should never have gotten to the point where you can see it.  You actually did complete 20 suggested edits **prior** to getting this audit so when you tried submitting a 21st review, you got thank you rather than congratulations.  I'm not sure why it gave you a 21st review instead of "thank you", though.